# How to remove mysterious spacing between layout level elements

Tags: css, html

For some reason I am getting spacing appearing between several layout level elements on a page (see fiddlejs [example](https://jsfiddle.net/suj05ekq/2/)). The result I am after is to have elements (marked by different colored backgrounds) flushed with each other (i.e. no spacing should exist between them).  I have not been able to find any explanation for why this spacing is occurring.

```css
.layout-content {
  background-color: gainsboro; 
}

aside {
  background-color: pink; 
}

header {
  background-color: chocolate; 
}

main {
  background-color: peachpuff; 
}

footer {
  background-color: orange; }
```

```html
<body class="path-node node--type-page">
  <div class="layout-container">
    <header role="banner">
      <div class="name-and-slogan">
         <strong class="site-name">
           <a href="http://awesome.dev/" title="Home" rel="home">awesome.dev</a>
         </strong>
      </div>    
    </header>
    <main role="main">
      <div class="layout-content">
        <div class="region region-primary-menu">
          <nav id="block-bens-main-menu" class="contextual-region block block-menu navigation menu--main" role="navigation" aria-labelledby="block-bens-main-menu-menu">
            <h2 id="block-bens-main-menu-menu" class="visually-hidden">Main navigation</h2>
            <div data-contextual-id="block:block=bens_main_menu:|menu:menu=main:"></div>
          </nav>
        </div>
        <nav class="breadcrumb" role="navigation" aria-labelledby="system-breadcrumb">
          <h2 id="system-breadcrumb" class="visually-hidden">Breadcrumb</h2>
        </nav>
        <h1><span data-quickedit-field-id="node/1/title/en/full" class="field field-node--title field-name-title field-type-string field-label-hidden">First Page</span></h1>
        <div class="region region-content">
          <div id="block-bens-content" class="block block-system">
            <article data-history-node-id="1" data-quickedit-entity-id="node/1" role="article" class="contextual-region node node--type-page node--view-mode-full" about="/node/1" typeof="schema:WebPage">
              <div data-contextual-id="node:node=1:changed=1423727643"></div>  <span property="schema:name" content="First Page" class="hidden"></span>
                <div class="node__content">
                  <div data-quickedit-field-id="node/1/body/en/full" class="clearfix field field-node--body field-name-body field-type-text-with-summary field-label-hidden">
                    <div class="field-items">
                      <div property="schema:text" class="field-item">
                        <p>Blocks in Drupal 8 are actually made up of two separate API structures to create a user experience similar to what Drupal has maintained in past terations. These two APIs are the Block Plugin API, which is a tand-alone reusable API and the Block Entity API which is a Drupal 8 pecific use case of block placement and visibility control.</p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="node__links"></div>
            </article>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <aside class="layout-sidebar-first" role="complementary">
        <div class="region region-sidebar-first">
          <div id="block-bens-login" class="contextual-region block block-user" role="form">
            <h2>User login</h2>
            <div data-contextual-id="block:block=bens_login:"></div>
            <form class="user-login-form" action="/node/1?destination=node/1" method="post" id="user-login-form" accept-charset="UTF-8">
              <div class="form-item form-type-textfield form-item-name">
                <label for="edit-name" class="form-required">Username</label>
                <input autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" aria-describedby="edit-name--description" id="edit-name" name="name" size="15" maxlength="60" class="form-text required" required="required" aria-required="true" type="text">
              </div>
              <div class="form-item form-type-password form-item-pass">
                <label for="edit-pass" class="form-required">Password</label>
                <input aria-describedby="edit-pass--description" id="edit-pass" name="pass" size="15" maxlength="128" class="form-text required" required="required" aria-required="true" type="password">
              </div>
                <input name="form_build_id" value="form-ubxpmZ4n7PBE7JFYvmxsoutesVPNmEkyTHj83_aY-6c" type="hidden">
                <input name="form_id" value="user_login_form" type="hidden">
              <div class="form-actions form-wrapper" id="edit-actions">
                <input id="edit-submit" name="op" value="Log in" class="button form-submit" type="submit">
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </aside>
  </main>
  <footer role="contentinfo">
    <div id="footer-columns" class="clearfix">
      <div class="layout-footer-firstcolumn">  
        <div class="region region-footer-firstcolumn">
          <div data-quickedit-entity-id="block_content/1" id="block-footerone-2" class="contextual-region block block-block-content">
            <h2>Footer One</h2>
            <div data-contextual-id="block:block=footerone_2:|block_content:block_content=1:changed=1423742303"></div>
            <div data-quickedit-field-id="block_content/1/body/en/full" class="clearfix field field-block-content--body field-name-body field-type-text-with-summary field-label-hidden">
              <div class="field-items">
                <div class="field-item">
                  <p>Assertively restore backend meta-services through intermandated methodologies. Rapidiously reintermediate client-focused scenarios after cost effective partnerships.</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="layout-footer-secondcolumn"></div>
      <div class="layout-footer-thirdcolumn"></div>
      <div class="layout-footer-fourthcolumn"></div>
    </div>
  </footer>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some headers, which on most browsers have some margin by default.

You can use this CSS reset:

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}
.layout-content {
  background-color: gainsboro;
}
aside {
  background-color: pink;
}
header {
  background-color: chocolate;
}
main {
  background-color: peachpuff;
}
footer {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="layout-container">
  <header role="banner">
    <div class="name-and-slogan">
      <strong class="site-name">
        <a href="http://awesome.dev/" title="Home" rel="home">awesome.dev</a>
      </strong>
    </div>
  </header>
  <main role="main">
    <div class="layout-content">
      <div class="region region-primary-menu">
        <nav id="block-bens-main-menu" class="contextual-region block block-menu navigation menu--main" role="navigation" aria-labelledby="block-bens-main-menu-menu">
          <h2 id="block-bens-main-menu-menu" class="visually-hidden">Main navigation</h2>
          <div data-contextual-id="block:block=bens_main_menu:|menu:menu=main:"></div>
        </nav>
      </div>
      <nav class="breadcrumb" role="navigation" aria-labelledby="system-breadcrumb">
        <h2 id="system-breadcrumb" class="visually-hidden">Breadcrumb</h2>
      </nav>
      <h1><span data-quickedit-field-id="node/1/title/en/full" class="field field-node--title field-name-title field-type-string field-label-hidden">First Page</span></h1>
      <div class="region region-content">
        <div id="block-bens-content" class="block block-system">
          <article data-history-node-id="1" data-quickedit-entity-id="node/1" role="article" class="contextual-region node node--type-page node--view-mode-full" about="/node/1" typeof="schema:WebPage">
            <div data-contextual-id="node:node=1:changed=1423727643"></div> <span property="schema:name" content="First Page" class="hidden"></span>
            <div class="node__content">
              <div data-quickedit-field-id="node/1/body/en/full" class="clearfix field field-node--body field-name-body field-type-text-with-summary field-label-hidden">
                <div class="field-items">
                  <div property="schema:text" class="field-item">
                    <p>Blocks in Drupal 8 are actually made up of two separate API structures to create a user experience similar to what Drupal has maintained in past terations. These two APIs are the Block Plugin API, which is a tand-alone reusable API
                      and the Block Entity API which is a Drupal 8 pecific use case of block placement and visibility control.</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="node__links"></div>
          </article>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <aside class="layout-sidebar-first" role="complementary">
      <div class="region region-sidebar-first">
        <div id="block-bens-login" class="contextual-region block block-user" role="form">
          <h2>User login</h2>
          <div data-contextual-id="block:block=bens_login:"></div>
          <form class="user-login-form" action="/node/1?destination=node/1" method="post" id="user-login-form" accept-charset="UTF-8">
            <div class="form-item form-type-textfield form-item-name">
              <label for="edit-name" class="form-required">Username</label>
              <input autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" aria-describedby="edit-name--description" id="edit-name" name="name" size="15" maxlength="60" class="form-text required" required="required" aria-required="true" type="text">
            </div>
            <div class="form-item form-type-password form-item-pass">
              <label for="edit-pass" class="form-required">Password</label>
              <input aria-describedby="edit-pass--description" id="edit-pass" name="pass" size="15" maxlength="128" class="form-text required" required="required" aria-required="true" type="password">
            </div>
            <input name="form_build_id" value="form-ubxpmZ4n7PBE7JFYvmxsoutesVPNmEkyTHj83_aY-6c" type="hidden">
            <input name="form_id" value="user_login_form" type="hidden">
            <div class="form-actions form-wrapper" id="edit-actions">
              <input id="edit-submit" name="op" value="Log in" class="button form-submit" type="submit">
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </aside>
  </main>
  <footer role="contentinfo">
    <div id="footer-columns" class="clearfix">
      <div class="layout-footer-firstcolumn">
        <div class="region region-footer-firstcolumn">
          <div data-quickedit-entity-id="block_content/1" id="block-footerone-2" class="contextual-region block block-block-content">
            <h2>Footer One</h2>
            <div data-contextual-id="block:block=footerone_2:|block_content:block_content=1:changed=1423742303"></div>
            <div data-quickedit-field-id="block_content/1/body/en/full" class="clearfix field field-block-content--body field-name-body field-type-text-with-summary field-label-hidden">
              <div class="field-items">
                <div class="field-item">
                  <p>Assertively restore backend meta-services through intermandated methodologies. Rapidiously reintermediate client-focused scenarios after cost effective partnerships.</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="layout-footer-secondcolumn"></div>
      <div class="layout-footer-thirdcolumn"></div>
      <div class="layout-footer-fourthcolumn"></div>
    </div>
  </footer>
</div>
```

Comment: extending the answer: it's about UA (userAgent) styles set by browser, the solution is to reset these like Oriol said

Answer (score 3):

You can start looking at developer tools of chrome where you can understand more about rendering of html elements.. Check the image attached for one such instance. Your h2(id="block-bens-main-menu-menu") tag has by default margin-top & margin-botom values which is actually creating the space. Investigate more by yourself ;) 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Extending a little bit the answer of Oriol: You have some headings (h1-h6) which are rendered in different ways by different browser. You can reset this styles manually or you can link a css file to your html or import it to your css or scss file.

Here are some css libraries that reset: [reset.css](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) and [normalize.css](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Actually, when I first encountered this issue, I had been building the CSS with sass/compass including the use of its 'normalize' extension, which I thought would have addressed this issue.  It sees strange to me that the 'normalize' extension would not include a margin reset.